# Length property in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run the following code in browser console:

```
console.log(length); //output is 1 in Chrome console
```

In some other IDE, the output is 0.

My question is why the output is 1 even if I haven't declared any variable length.

Comment: Without context it's not possible to answer your question.  For example, I just opened the console on this page and typed ` console.log(length);` and it returned 3 - I had not defined this var myself.

Comment: [`window.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length)

Comment: Normally, if you haven't defined a variable, the scope will revert to window properties. In this case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length  . If there are frames inside your test scenario, it would return a value.

Comment: @Yeah Not sure....why you thought that this is not a programming question. It's, in fact, the most basic scenario. Without declaring any variable, how can it return any value.....it should be undefined.

Comment: It should not be `undefined`, read Me.Name's comment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Google Chrome is a web browser not an IDE.

[image]

As you can see on this small screenshot, on Google Chrome the variable length seems linked to the "Window" so it's already declared by the system. That's why you have a value by default.

Comment: But even If I am doing the same in any IDE, the result is not undefined as expected. It is always an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Getting `length` in Chrome console infers getting [Window.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length) - returning the number of frames in the `Window` object.

Doing so in an IDE does not infer Window and therefore should return a Ref Error where length is undefined. It really would depend on your IDE's environment.